# Slave database is ok but get corrupted when promoted as master

Tags: postgresql, replication, corruption

I have had a problem with a PostgreSQL database that is replicated on several machines.
On the master server, I had requests that failed with

```
missing chunk number 121 for toast value 146485 in pg_toast_35064
```

The same requests were working fine on the replicas.
I thought the problem was hardware-related. So I decided to migrate the master VM to a different hardware, purge the database and rebuild it as a replica.

I tried to run the failing request on the new replica and it worked fine. So I promoted it as the new master and the same request immediately failed…

Any idea where the problem may come from?

Comment: I find that hard to believe. Did the `ctid` of the affected row change between the time when it worked and the time when it failed?

Comment: I also could not believe that, but I renewed the experience, on a different machine, with the same result. For the record, a REINDEX solved the problem on the new master, but I still can't understand why a corrupted index causes a failure on a master cluster but not on a read-only hot-standby…

Comment: Also, I have no idea how to check the `ctid` of the row or to find the offending row in the toast table.

Comment: This is TOAST corruption. Try to identify the problematic row and look at the binary data with pageinspect.